# Microservices: Maintaining compatibility for model classes between old and new jar versions as we're growing

Tags: java, model, jar, microservices, backwards-compatibility

I'm working on a microservices architecture, I have an old jar version v1.2 and a new jar version v1.6. I have added new fields and models classes to v1.6 which are not present in v1.2.

For example:

Jar v1.2

```java
public class Base{
    private Temp1 temp1;  
}
```

Jar v1.6

```java
public class Base{
    private Temp1 temp1;   
    private Temp2 temp2;  
}
```

Class Temp2 is not present in v1.2 and the newer service is deployed as per 1.6. There's a team working on v1.2 and facing a parsing exception for the field temp2 as they are getting temp2=null.

I am not able to understand the issue because it's running in production without any problem. How do I fix this issue and maintain the backward compatibility for such cases?